# How to start process by user, than continue with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I'm trying to login in to udemy.com but udemy detects that, then asks for captcha etc. Also I tried to sleep selenium and do captcha myself, again it is not accepted by hcaptcha.

**Can I log in to udemy myself, than give the management to selenium to do the process, is it possible?**

Or any other ways to login to udemy, or other sites that need captcha?

Comment: You can login, then share that user directory (in chrome) to stay logged in. Or you can start the script, wait for user input, then continue.

Comment: actually i tried that, started the process then make the python wait for an input. But udemy can detect that i use an browser that is managed by a bot, it doesn't allow me to log in with this browser in any case.